# tsql source control using msscci

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, sql-server-2005, tfs

I have the TFS MSSCCI installed, now what? How do I use it to put say like a stored procedure under source control?

Thanks,
rodchar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to version control sprocs is to make a SQL script that installs the stored procedure, perhaps of the form

```
if object_id ('FooSproc') is not null
    drop procedure FooSproc
go

Create procedure FooSproc
[ . . . ]
go
```

Put the scripts in source control.

**Versioning and releasing a larger body of stored procedure code**

You may also need to sort out a means of compiling multiple scripts into a single installer for sprocs.  A quick and dirty way that actually works quite well is to use the C preprocessor and files with a bunch of #include statements.  The C preprocessor comes with Visual Studio or the free SDK that you can download from Microsoft's web site.

```
-- =========================================================================
-- === Installer file for FooApp sprocs ====================================
-- =========================================================================
--
--          THIS IS GENERATED CODE.  EDITS WILL BE OVERWRITTEN.
--
-- =========================================================================
--
#include "Foo.sql"

#include "Bar.sql"

#include "Wibble.sql"
```

With a bit of scripting you can make a release manager that lets you check out all of the sprocs for a given version of your application and install that version into a database.  Of course, don't forget to update the include file or the installer will miss anything not included.

In order to use the C preprocessor you need to set up your environment.  Visual studio ships with a batch file to do this that will typically end up installed somewhere like:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 8\VC\vcvarsall.bat
```

You need to run the batch file to set up the environment, and then you can run the C preprocessor with an incantation like:

```
cl /EP DB\DB.inc > Build\DB\DB.sql
```

This will read an include file, include all of the files it references and then write to stdout; you can redirect stdout anywhere that takes your fancy.  Note that the C preprocessor is recursive and you can include other include files.

Comment: Alright I have my sql script in front of me, what do I do now to add it to source control?

Comment: I think my problem here is my SSMS might be an express version because I don't see a solution explorer

Comment: SQL Server dev ed. is pretty cheap (<$50).  That would get you a version of SSMS that supports source control.  Also, if you have legit SQL Server licencing the install CD or image for that will have a version of SSMS that supports source control.